# issue with the radio button not binding together with model property

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, radio-button

HI I am trying to set radio button on the form, and submit it through a form submit action. The problem is that while debugging the model property SendEmail is not getting set. 
Below is the code that I am using, and I cannot figure out (due to lack of experience with front end debugging). If someone has any pointers or any suggestions that will be helpful. 
Just to run you through the code. I have 3 radio buttons which I am binding with the model property SendEmail. I than submit the form by calling javascript function on Yes Button which inherently submits the form. Now when I use the breakpoint in the Model class to see if the property is set, I see null.

```
<script>
    $('#ExchangeChangeConfirmationDiv').on("click", "#BtnSubmit", function () {
        showLoadingImage();
        if ($("#ProcessConsumerExchangeChange").valid()) {
            $("#ProcessConsumerExchangeChange").submit();
            HideConfirmationModal();
        }
        else {
            hideLoadingImage();
            return false;
        }
    });
```

```
<div id="ExchangeChangeConfirmationDiv" class="modal modal-sm">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div id="inline_content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h2>Process Change</h2>
                <div class="modal-close" data-dismiss="modal">close</div>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-body">
                <input type="hidden" id="DeleteID" />
                <div>
                    Are you sure you wish to process this exchange change request?
                    <br /><br />
                    This action cannot be undone without sizable administrative effort.
                    <br /><br />
                    Please save a copy of the employee's existing coverages before performing this step.
                </div>

                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <br />
                    Do you want to notify customer?
                    <br />
                    @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.SendEmail, "E-Mail")

                    @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.SendEmail, "PDF")

                    @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.SendEmail, "Cancel")
                </div>

                <div class="centeredButtons">
                    <div class="clearfix">
                        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="button blue" data-dismiss="modal">No</a>
                        <a id="BtnSubmit" href="javascript:void(0);" class="button green">Yes</a>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
Model Class:

    public string SendEmail { get; set; }
```

Comment: Are those buttons inside your `<form id="ProcessConsumerExchangeChange">` tags?

Comment: No. ProcessConsumerExchangeChange calls the modal, which has these radio buttons. So I guess I want to ask is how do I attach these radio button declared in the modal with the form in the background?

Comment: The buttons need to be inside your form (you could just move all the html inside `<div id="ExchangeChangeConfirmationDiv">`). Alternatively you could have a hidden input with `name="SendEmail"` and sets its value when you click button or call your `.submit()` method